# syntax error for changing user role from database

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I want to change user role from the database,

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
SET meta_value = 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}' 
WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
AND meta_value = 'a:1:{s:9:"wpas_user";b:1;}';
```

but I get an error.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''a:1:{s:10:"subscriber")' at line 1

Comment: Is that the exact code you're running? I didn't receive any error when I ran that query.

Comment: sure `http://s8.picofile.com/file/8362076834/ttttt.PNG`

Comment: @JacobPeattie I found the problem. it cause two `;`. how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

It was a field in phpMyAdmin which is set to a semicolon(;) by default.

I have changed it to an unused char and the query ran normally.

[image]